# My wifi is getting connected but not working on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, realtek-wireless

My laptop is HP (15-ac189nia). After getting dual boot, wifi is not working properly on ubuntu while it works fine on windows.
On connecting with wifi, it shows " wifi connected" but it doesn't work.
I have also updated my system but of no use.

```
lshw -c net
```

The output of this command is as follows:

```
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 07
       serial: 70:5a:0f:ba:ca:aa
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8106e-1_0.0.1 06/29/12 ip=10.3.16.241 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:123 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:a1200000-a1200fff memory:a1000000-a1003fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 00
       serial: 44:1c:a8:73:a2:e5
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8723be driverversion=4.4.0-72-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.8.24 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       resources: irq:17 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:a1100000-a1103fff
WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program as super-user.
```

When i run traceroute 8.8.8.8 using my laptop wifi, it gives error as follows:

```
azka@azka-HP-Notebook:~$ traceroute 8.8.8.8
traceroute to 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
connect: Network is unreachable
```

When i run the same command using TP-Link (Wifi USB adapter), it gives output as follows:

```
azka@azka-HP-Notebook:~$ traceroute 8.8.8.8
traceroute to 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  192.168.8.1 (192.168.8.1)  4.521 ms  4.719 ms  4.991 ms
 2  * * *
 3  10.81.195.233 (10.81.195.233)  52.864 ms  52.836 ms  52.811 ms
 4  10.57.191.185 (10.57.191.185)  59.339 ms  59.316 ms 10.81.195.181 (10.81.195.181)  59.229 ms
 5  10.81.195.198 (10.81.195.198)  52.652 ms 10.57.191.178 (10.57.191.178)  52.629 ms 10.81.195.198 (10.81.195.198)  52.572 ms
 6  10.81.191.21 (10.81.191.21)  52.472 ms  33.655 ms  33.101 ms
 7  59.103.253.25 (59.103.253.25)  36.962 ms  37.694 ms  37.225 ms
 8  static-khi275-P02-pie.net.pk (221.120.254.6)  61.174 ms  61.704 ms  61.920 ms
 9  static.khi77.pie.net.pk (202.125.128.135)  65.371 ms  65.332 ms  64.948 ms
10  72.14.242.93 (72.14.242.93)  207.985 ms  208.354 ms  199.956 ms
11  209.85.244.252 (209.85.244.252)  192.450 ms 209.85.244.250 (209.85.244.250)  199.633 ms 209.85.244.252 (209.85.244.252)  199.135 ms
12  * * *
13  * * *
14  * * *
```

Comment: What happens when you run a `traceroute` on an address like 8.8.8.8?

Comment: Output has been added in original comment